# Update MSI Tables with Query

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, windows-installer

Iam new at this topic so please forgive me if my question is not reasonable. Iam using an installer for 3 assemblies. One of those assemlies i have to change a value of Type column. My Problem is, i can't say, which one is the one i need to change to the value of it because they are refered to an action KEY. I dont know, what is the key for the assemly i wanna update it's value. I'm using for that the program super orca. as you can see in the screeshot, i have for each assembly an install, comit, rollback and uninstall row.

Also is it possible to write a query somewhere inside VIsual studio, so i dont have to edit manuelly every time i compile a new version?
[image]

Comment: which installer builder are you using? is it clickonce from visual studio ?

Comment: I'm using the Setup Project from Visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have answer to the first question (Orca editor) but for the Visual studio part, you have two possibilities

possibility 1 - if possible, in visual studio set up post build actions to change properties of assembly files on the project which is producing your assemblies; if changing properties here is also reflected in installer that you build then you are done.

possibility 2 - create custom action in setup/installer project; this custom action executes when installer is executed. Custom action need to have code to change property of assembly through/during installation. This doesn't change the properties in installer but it changes properties of installed assemblies. Here is the [example on how to write custom action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/cc982255(v=vs.85)#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Custom%20Actions%20Editor,project%2C%20and%20then%20click%20OK.)

a hack - for orca editor - given that there are only three assemblies, you could try changing property one at a time and execute installer to see if it changed property of the right assembly.